# Why does the sequence matter in the execution of these bash commands?

Tags: bash

There seems to be some inconsistency that I am not able to understand regarding the bash shell.

If I execute:

`ls;date;time`

the results of the three queries are shown in sequence.

However, on interchanging date and time position, an error message pops up.

So if I execute:

`ls;time;date`

the error message says: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'date'`.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Your problem lies on `time;date` vs `date;time`. This seems to be a problem with pipeline in `bash` and last char generated with `time` output. Tested results in different terminal emulators are: - [Bash] $ date;time # [OK] $ time;date # [**NotOK**] bash:syntax error near unexpected token `date ' $ time # only error does not appear that it is the result of any date. - [Csh] $ date;time # [OK] $ time;date # [OK] - [Tcsh] $ date;time # [OK] $ time;date # [OK] - [Ksh] $ date;time # [OK] $ time;date # [OK]

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation for the error message. Please check that this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 10):

The `time` command in your pipeline is not the `/usr/bin/time` binary, but the bash `time` built-in. Compare `man time` with `help time`. The error you see is bash failing to parse `time`'s argument. This must either be present or be a newline. It is a newline in your first example but absent in the second.

On the other hand, if you were to run

```
ls;date;'time'
```

or

```
ls;'time';date
```

where the quotes around `'time'` revoke its status as a reserved word, then bash has no problems parsing the line. It now parses three commands in a list, which it will execute in sequence, and `/usr/bin/time` will report a usage error in either case.

**Addendum**

It was observed that though `time ; date` yields an error, `time ; ; date` does not. The likely explanation is that `time ;` is interpreted by bash as equivalent to `time <newline>`. The expression `time ; ; date` is then parsed as the list of `time ;` and `date`.

This is consistent with the observation that `time ;` and `time ; ;` are legal as well, the second being parsed as the singleton list containing `time ;` followed by the optional semicolon allowed after lists.

So another way of explaining why `time ; date` yields the error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'date'` is that `time` consumes the semicolon separating it from `date`. It can only do that because `time` is a bash reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation! But then again this behaviour looks like a bug to me: `time` is supposed to allow a NULL command, and semicolon is supposed to delimit lists, so IMO the `time` command shouldn't "consume" the semicolon after it. Other builtin commands (which can take arguments) do not exhibit this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @arrange The complication is that time does not allow a null command (that would have disambiguated everything), it only allows a *newline* in place of the command. So `time;date` is indeed syntactically wrong in any interpretation. **However** `time ;` and `time ; ;` would then also be illegal. It can be debated whether `time`'s behaviour is a bug or merely undocumented (it *is* internally consistent), but a bug report would definitely be in place. Would you be willing to file it?

Comment: Well, I looked at the source (bash4.2:parse.y:lines 1205-1221) and there it says that `time by itself can time a null command` and then it does so by `$$ = make_simple_command (x, (COMMAND *)NULL);`. As for filing a bug I'm not sure 8)

Comment: Should be noted that this issue is bash-specific. Doing `time ; date` works in `ksh93` and `mksh` with no errors, even though in `ksh`  there's `time` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Bash treats the built-in `time` as a special case, when parsing command-lines.

As can be read in the bash manpage, the line as typed is first split into a list:

```
pipeline ; pipeline
```

where a pipeline is:

```
[time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]
```

or in our case, simply:

```
time command
```

i.e. if time is present, then command **must** also be present.

[There is a special case that allows `time` to be followed by a newline, but that doesn't apply here]

So, in our case, we have:

```
time;date
```

being split into two pipelines:

```
1. time
2. date
```

and pipeline 1 is not well formed, since we have `time` without a command. Hence the error.

Note that the command-line `time` doesn't work here either:

```
$ /usr/bin/time;date
Usage: /usr/bin/time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
```

bash parses this as expected, into 2 pipelines:

```
1. /usr/bin/time
2. date
```

and `/usr/bin/time` then refuses to run with no argument. Note that this is an error from `/usr/bin/time` not an error from bash.

The reason that back-tick works is that the back-tick stops `time` being interpreted as a special element within the pipeline.

i.e. with the back-tick:

```
`time`;date
```

it is parsed as two pipelines:

```
1. `time`
2. date
```

Remember that a pipeline, in our case, is:

```
[time] command
```

and the problem initially was that we had `time` with no command, which isn't allowed. But now we simply have the command:

```
`time`
```

without the preceding `time`, since the back-ticks mean that `time` is interpreted as the command, not as a preceding word.

So bash then runs its builtin `time` with no args, which is accepted. It produces no output, and we see no error.

Note that:

```
`time`
```

actually runs the **result** of the `time` built-in, i.e. it runs whatever the `time` built-in produces on stdout. But since `time` on its own doesn't write anything to stdout, it appears to work.

Finally, it's been noted that this works:

```
time ; ; date
```

which I can't explain, sadly :)

Comment: I think your explanation is better, but it still looks weird to me. `;date` gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ;`, but `time ;date` gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token date`, so it seems bash doesn't treat the command after the time builtin as ";date". Interestingly, `time ; ; date` works.

Comment: yup, thanks @arrange, it's quite weird. I'll update the answer slightly.

Comment: ok, @arrange, have rewritten. Still can't explain your last though... sigh.

Comment: @cdmackay You are mixing up backticks and quotes. By *quoting* `'time'` it loses its meaning as a reserved word. *Backticking* it makes it execute in a subshell whose output gets spliced into the command. This has nothing to do with the discussion. As a matter of fact, your example `\`time\';date` proves the contrary of your claim: this _should_ give an error by your reasoning because `/usr/bin/time` requires an argument. The reason it doesn't is because in the subshell in which it executes it is the reserved word `time` once again.

Comment: @arrange Both are syntax errors and both are reported to be *near* the same place, so I don't see an inconsistency there. Once it enters syntax error land, you can't expect a parser to know its way out. If you would require that of a parser, then it must know not only the legal syntax, but also the _syntax_ of every possible illegal construct, which is impossible by definition.